# function or variable outside of a class in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was exploring react, and I saw this piece of code.

```
const renderLine = (user, key) => <li key={key}><b>{key}</b>: {user[key]}</li>

export default class App extends Component {
  ...
  ...
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
          {Object.keys(user).map(key => renderLine(user, key))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Why the renderLine is outside of the App class? What's the intention of this pattern? Usually I will just put inside a class and use it like `this.renderLine()`

Comment: this is useful only when you might have multiple components in one file (which one hardly does) and more than one of them use the function. Else this can be useful just in case you might want to export `readLine`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put it in the class, for sure, without any problem. Exposing it outside the class makes it a helper function that can be used outside the class/component's scope.

You can even organise these kind of code into a helper function outside this js file, e.g. UIHelper.js:

```
//UIHelper.js
const renderLine = (user, key) => <li key={key}><b>{key}</b>: {user[key]}

const UIHelper = {
    renderLabel: renderLabel,        //Other helper functions
    renderLine: renderLine,          //<----------Export this
    renderDateTime: renderDateTime,  //Other helper functions
    ...
}
export default UIHelper;
```

Usage:

```
//Other.js
import UIHelper from '../what/ever/path/UIHelper'

render (){
...
   {UIHelper.renderLine()}
...
}
```

Comment: Exporting them as default will prevent functions from being tree-shaken. Why not named export?

Comment: It make sense when you put the renderLine in a separate file, but in above case why is it in the same file?

Comment: @CasaLim, no one forces you doing so. Note the word "also", thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Reusable is the answer. Putting it in your class and you can't use it in another component.

In React there are two main type of components: stateful and stateless. You use stateless components to render small things that don't own its data. `renderLine` is the perfect example: it just render whatever you give it, in a line.

Comment: The answer is correct. But notice that it isn't stateless comp, just helper function.

Comment: Reuse like how? If it's on another file it's understood, but in above case it's above the class as a variable.

Comment: @CasaLim It is not a normal variable but rather a pure function. Yes, the code above only exists in one file but if you add export before it then it's another story.

Comment: @HuyVo, wrote `console.log('something')` above component. It `logged` though the component is not mounted and `logged` only once. Does that mean everything we write above the component going to become global variable?

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu not sure what you mean, which line exactly that you put console.log?

Answer (score 1):

A function is same as a stateless component.
However it's less common to write it this way, since the components inside mapping function require `key`, but not every row need to display the key value.

```js
const renderLine = (user, key) => (<li key={key}><b>{key}</b>:{user}</li>);

const RenderStatelessLine = props => (<li>{props.user}</li>);

export default class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
          {Object.keys(users).map(key => renderLine(users[key], key))}
          {Object.keys(users).map(key => <RenderStatelessLine user={users[key]} key={key} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: if you put within class you can't reuse? I can do multiple times of `this.renderLine()` too

Comment: @CasaLim good call. It's more resueable. It can be used by another stateless component. So you can easily refactoring your code later on. And the compiled js file is slightly shorter this way.

Comment: which way? are you saying `this.renderLine()` is better than doing it like the code above?

Comment: @CasaLim No I'm saying  either way in the example above is slightly better than write a function inside class. Writing stateless component is the most preferred way right now, which used by many 3rd party lib. Eg react-router